# How do I delete every element of list of string that starts with a string from that list?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
  ["12", "123", "145", "178", "1264"]
```

I want to find a way of changing that list. If one of the string holds an already present string in the list it should be deleted. For the given list above, it has element `12` so every element that starts with `12` should be removed from the list. The list should look like this after.

```
["12", "145", "178"]
```

I have a way of solving this with loops. But I'm looking for a more Python-like solution. I was reading about list comprehensions and tried to use them to solve this but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @dreygur Are you looking for a solution with loops or the one I tried with list comprehensions?

Comment: The code you wrote for list comprehension

Comment: @dreygur `l2 = [x for x in l1 if x == x[:len(x)]]` l1 is the list from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
l1 = ["12", "123", "145", "178", "1264"]
l2 = [a for a in l1 if a not in [n for n in l1 for length in range(len(n)) if n[:length] in l1]]
```